# Angular: Posting Data to a Table with a loop and giving a problem when posting the i of the loop into the table

Tags: mysql, angular, loops, post, indexing

Good day,

I am trying to get data into a table, with the tour_id and every single media_id (the station_id i am getting from somewhere else), the ordernumber is what is giving me a headache:
I am trying to get every station one number for every media i am posting.

For example: 
station 1 has 2 medias
and station 2 has 3

then the odernumbers should be like this: 0, 0, 1, 1, 1

I am using the following Code at this moment:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.currentStations.length; i++){
              this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/mediasforstation/" + this.currentStations[i].id).subscribe((res) => {
                medias = res;

                for (var j = 0; j < medias.length; j++){
                  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/posttourstations",
                  {"tour_id": id,  "media_id": medias[j].id, "ordernumber": i}).subscribe(function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                  }.bind(this));
                }
              });
            }
```

Everything but the ordernumber works, however, the ordernumber always takes the number of stations involved, in our example above it would be 2.

How do I fix this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to keep the index value. The type of variable `i` is `var` which is `function scoped`. Within outer loop, you are calling an API that returns some response, meanwhile the value of `i` is updated and for next index/counter, the API call has been sent. When you get response from API calls, you get the value of `i` where the outer loop has been called of.

In other words, you need to understand the difference between `var` and `let`. Your problem can be solved by replacing

```
     for(var i=0;...)
```

with

```
     for(let i=0;...)
```

Here's providing you the sample code.

```
     //block scoped - retains value of i
     for (let i=0;i<10;i++){
        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(res=>{
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
            console.log(`i=>${i}`)
        }
       })
      }

     //function scoped - gets updated value of i
     for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
        http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(res=>{
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
           console.log(`i=>${i}`)
        }
      })

    }
```